# Do I need assembly versions at all if I never work with the GAC?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, semantic-versioning, assemblyversions

I never used assembly versions in my .NET Core/5/6 projects until today.
I understand that it can make sense to have different assembly versions loaded into the GAC from time to time, but in my own development process I never use the GAC.

I also read many times that using it is not recommended anymore, because all necessary Dlls will be kept in the local directory of the project.

Therefore my assemblies all have the version **1.0.0.0** and I only use NuGet packages to keep track of the versioning of them.

However, I just read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning) article and it seems that I should re-think my assembly versions:

What this article states is the following:

> ❌ DO NOT have a fixed AssemblyVersion.
>
> While an unchanging AssemblyVersion avoids the need for binding redirects, it means that only a single version of the assembly can be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). Also, the applications that reference the assembly in the GAC will break if another application updates the GAC assembly with breaking changes.

However, only the GAC is mentioned here as a reason.

If I create NuGet Packages for all my libraries and I follow Semantic versioning 2.0 principles, I never had issues with my assembly versions.

Do I need to care about the assembly version, if I never use the GAC?

Comment: The bullet before that suggests you keep the major version aligned between this and the NuGet package, so that would be a reason to change the version that's not related to the GAC

Comment: Does you project has name or it is like Project5 or test3?

Comment: But if my NuGet package already has a version, why should I care about the assembly version? I can of course keep the major version in sync, but I would like to understand the purpose

Comment: Again, if you *read* the bullet before the one quoted, it *gives* a reason for keeping the versions aligned.

Comment: There’s no GAC for .net core

Comment: @DanielA.White So only better error messages are the reason? I think this would not be enough for me, to put so much effort in another versioning scheme...

Answer (score 1):

Assembly version is also part of the assembly identity, which means that when it changes, *technically* it is considered a different assembly; on .NET Framework you need to hack around that by using "assembly binding redirects" at the application level (via the config); this is awkward and *can* lead to broken applications - fortunately this is almost entirely a thing of the past in .NET Core / .NET 5+, *but*: because of this history, many popular public libraries *do* keep a fixed assembly version, *precisely so that* it doesn't constantly break .NET Framework consumers - using other assembly attributes to convey the actual full version information.

Short version: in reality, I think you'll be just fine ignoring that advice.

Comment: "Short version: in reality, I think you'll be just fine ignoring that advice." - So if I never use .NET Framework and nobody who does uses my libs, I can just ignore the assembly version?

Comment: @DavidMason IMO you can mostly ignore it *even then*

Comment: IMO, strong naming was a stupid hack that never provided the security benefits it claimed to provide.